# Codeigniter - Somente uma linha de um LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho uma tabela que e relacionada pelo id da outra. Uma contem os dados do documento, a outra contem as imagens relacionadas ao documento. Mais preciso que nesta consulta especifica seja retornado somente a primeira linha do tabela de imagens.

Segue minha consulta no Codeigniter:

```
function getConsulta($cidade,$classe,$busca,$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){
    $this->db->select("{$classe}.*, cidades.nome as nome_cidade, categorias.nome as nome_categoria, {$classe}_imagens.imagem as imagem_imagem");
    $this->db->from($classe);
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $this->db->join('cidades', "{$classe}.cidade_id = cidades.id", 'left');
    $this->db->join('categorias', "{$classe}.categoria_id = categorias.id", 'left');
    $this->db->join("{$classe}_imagens", "{$classe}.id = {$classe}_imagens.{$classe}_id", 'left');
    $this->db->where('cidades.id', $cidade);
    $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    if($busca){
        $this->db->like("{$classe}.nome",$busca)->or_like("categorias.nome",$busca);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result =  !$one  ? $query->result() : $query->row();
    return $result;
}
```

Hoje a consulta funciona normalmente, mais somente para quando se tem uma imagem na tabela de imagens. O fato que ocorre quando se tem mais de um registro no relacionamento e que ao retornar varias linhas o `foreach` interage com cada linha repetindo o resultado, mas com uma imagem diferente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->group_by('cidades.id');
```

Você vai precisar agrupar os resultados pela cidade.id.